# What are these log files(python3_657059_1698250083616.log) and how can I disable them?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, logging

Under ~/.ros/log I have a bunch of empty log files. What are they for, what generates them and how can I disable them? I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm on a source build ros_humble.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:08 python3_657059_1698250083616.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:08 python3_657488_1698250091844.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:08 python3_658021_1698250100224.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:08 python3_658432_1698250108468.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:08 python3_658886_1698250116802.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:08 python3_659308_1698250125026.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:08 python3_659728_1698250133116.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:09 python3_660153_1698250141399.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:09 python3_660666_1698250149626.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:09 python3_661092_1698250157917.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:09 python3_661523_1698250166126.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:09 python3_661938_1698250174376.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:09 python3_662373_1698250182579.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:09 python3_662796_1698250190693.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:09 python3_663224_1698250198942.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:10 python3_663664_1698250207174.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:10 python3_664082_1698250215341.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:10 python3_664498_1698250223535.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:10 python3_664916_1698250231652.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:10 python3_665366_1698250239854.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:10 python3_665779_1698250248045.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:10 python3_666201_1698250256283.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:11 python3_666642_1698250264491.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:11 python3_667059_1698250272658.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:11 python3_667483_1698250280844.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:11 python3_667897_1698250288967.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:11 python3_668311_1698250297097.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:11 python3_668732_1698250305221.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:11 python3_669142_1698250313435.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:12 python3_669555_1698250321566.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:12 python3_669995_1698250329785.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:12 python3_670420_1698250337962.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:12 python3_670851_1698250346147.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:12 python3_671297_1698250354280.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:12 python3_671715_1698250362459.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:12 python3_672132_1698250370660.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:12 python3_672559_1698250378814.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:13 python3_672984_1698250386990.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Oct 25 18:13 python3_673413_1698250395228.log
```

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
Just clean the log directory by `$ rm -rf ~/.ros/log`

Comment: I did that and they just reappear, see my other question: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104972/how-can-i-disable-all-logging-to-files-under-ros-but-still-log-to-stderr

Answer (score 1):

Using `lsof /home/username/.ros/log/*` I found the offending process `pid` with `pwdx pid` I found the program which was generating the log, which is a custom node I wrote in python.

I don't know how to stop the node from generating these logs, but that is a follow up question. The above answer should enable others to find out where the log files are coming from