# How can I disable all logging to files under ~/.ros but still log to stderr?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, logging

I read https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Concepts/Intermediate/About-Logging.html but that didn't really explain how one would go about it. Is it even possible? I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm on a source build ros_humble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable node log output with cli argument `--disable-external-lib-logs`, e.g.:

```
ros2 run <package> <executable> --ros-args --disable-external-lib-logs`
```

Similar arguments exist for `stdout` and `rosout`:

`--disable-stdout-logs`
`--disable-rosout-logs`

When using launch files, the launch script also generates a log file.
By default, the node stdout log is also written to that launch log file.

This can be disabled with `output='screen'` in the launch file, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='package_name',
            executable='executable_name',
            output='screen',
            arguments=[
              "--ros-args",
              "--disable-external-lib-logs"]
        ),
    ])
```

However, even then a folder and a launch log file is created in `~/.ros/log`.

I found [this related question](https://answers.ros.org/question/371795/ros2-disable-logging-to-file/) on the ROS Answers site.

I tried the answer by `WhatTheActual01` but I didn't succeed to not generate log files that way.

The answer by `hsaito` works fine though:

- Clone and compile [nullfs](https://github.com/xrgtn/nullfs):

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install -y git libfuse-dev build-essential
  git clone https://github.com/xrgtn/nullfs
  cd nullfs/
  make nullfs
  ```
- Make directory for, and run nullfs

  ```
  mkdir /tmp/empty_log_dir
  ./nullfs /tmp/empty_log_dir
  ```
- Set environment variable and run ROS 2:

  ```
  export ROS_LOG_DIR=/tmp/empty_log_dir
  ros2 launch launch_file.launch.py
  ```

Comment: The `--ros-args --disable-external-lib-logs` approach doesn't work for me because I start my node like a normal python file. It's just python my_file.py and in there I start a node. I would need a way on programmatic node creation to have a way to tell it to not log anything. For the launch file, I already had `output='screen'` but as you say I still get the empty folder. I also went with the same solution of redirecting everything to /tmp/ros, but it's not ideal, so I will leave the question open

Comment: I don't understand the issue you are still facing. Even if you start your node from an own python file instead of a launch file, at some point you will need to call `rclpy.init(args)` (see the [tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html#codecell5)), to which you can add any `args` as required, even if you don't provide them at the command line. Furthermore, if your actual issue is the empty folder: I provided a solution (I even tested it) using nullfs. So what else do you need to upvote and accept this answer?

Comment: I didn't think about passing the args to `rclpy.init(args)`. Good point