# How to I stop a ros2 node in python from generating an empty log file under ~/.ros/log?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, logging, rclpy

I have a custom node which I create in a Python program, the specifics don't matter since any basic node creates such a log file under `~/.ros/log`. How can I prevent that? I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 on a ros_humble source build.

Comment: This user asked a highly-similar question in https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104972/how-can-i-disable-all-logging-to-files-under-ros-but-still-log-to-stderr

Comment: Hmmm I wonder why...